# Loading a PHP extension at runtime results in Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function dl()

Tags: php, apache, php-extension

I am using **PHP 7.1.11** I am just trying this function `dl()`, but it shows an error.

I commented `php_fileinfo.dll` in `php.ini` and restarted the Apache.
I think the problem is not with `.dll` and so, the problem is with the `dl()` function.

Code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
echo phpversion();
   
echo PHP_OS;
if(!extension_loaded('fileinfo')){
    dl('php_fileinfo.dll');
}
...
```

Error thrown:

> 7.1.11WINNT Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function dl() in D:\xampp\htdocs\php\1.php:7
>
> Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\php\1.php on line 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `dl()` function was removed from most SAPIs some time ago and you are asked to use the [Extension Loading Directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension) instead.

The current [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) warns exactly about this.

**1. Documentation and history**

> **Warning**
>   This function was removed from most SAPIs in PHP 5.3.0, and was removed from PHP-FPM in PHP 7.0.0.

This is the full change history:

- **7.0.0**    `dl()` is disabled in PHP-FPM.
- **5.3.9**    `dl()` is enabled in PHP-FPM, albeit discouraged.
- **5.3.0**    `dl()` is now disabled in some SAPIs due to stability issues. The only SAPIs that allow `dl()` are *CLI* and *Embed*.

**2. Is there a solution?**

The real question is do you really need a solution? The `dl()` functions was deprecated for a reason after all.

> It's up to your system to support your codebase and not your codebase to make the system compliant.

Use the `extension_loaded()` function to check if the extension is loaded and if not raise a error/exception instead of trying to dynamically load it in runtime.

You can load all the extensions you want securely by using the system's `php.ini` file *extension directives*